# Which google sheets function can I use for this?

Tags: function, google-sheets

I have spreadsheet where I need to do the following:

O5*L5+O6*L6+O7*L7+O8*L8 (...) for a set number of rows (5-48).

What function can I use?

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT()`, I presume?

Comment: Thanks :) It helped

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is called [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).